# WP7 Calling NotifyComplete() after 25 seconds on a PeriodicTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, background-agents

I'm trying to understand why the NotifyComplete() method gets called even after the 25 second limit for a periodic task execution.

I understand that if notifyComplete() is not called befere 25 seconds, the task is killed, but this is not what is happening. NotifyComplete() is still get called after 60 seconds.

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{ 
    Thread.Sleep(60000); // 60 Seconds
    NotifyComplete();
}
```

Any Ideas?, I'm missunderstanding in some way the way the background agents work?
Thanks!

Comment: Is it happening on the phone or emulator or both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it happens while debugging.

> When running under the debugger, the memory and run-time constraints
>   are ignored by the Windows Phone operating system.

Comment: Hey thanks!; I actually thought about that but I didn't find it anywhere, I don't know why I did't actual try it in a release build..